# How to return the index of a vector that contains at least a string in another vector in R

Tags: r, string

I have a list containing verbs. I have another list containing sentences. How do I return the index of the sentence list that contains at least a verb in the verb list for that sentence?

```
verbList <- c("punching", "kicking", "jumping", "hopping")
sentenceList <- c("I am punching", "I like pineapples", "I am hopping", "I am kicking and jumping")
```

I want it to return indexes 1, 3, and 4

Comment: you have a string and a vector, not lists.

Comment: When you change your question, the answers no longer correspond to the question as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using no additional packages, we can sort of "or" different search terms together using `|` as follows:

Original question:

```
verbList <- list("punching, kicking, jumping, hopping")
sentenceList <- c("I am punching", "I like pineapples", "I am hopping", "I am kicking and jumping")

    v <- gsub(", ", "|", verbList) 
    grep(v, sentenceList)
```

New question:

```
verbList <- c("punching", "kicking", "jumping", "hopping")
sentenceList <- c("I am punching", "I like pineapples", "I am hopping", "I am kicking and jumping")
v <- paste(verbList, collapse = "|")
grep(v, sentenceList)
```

Comment: What if verbList was actually list and not a string (edited my original post). Is there a way to put in the "OR" then?

Comment: I understand, and I apologize for the changes. I won't change it again. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

A solution from `stringr` and `rebus`. We can first split the string, and then use `str_which` to check if the pattern is in the vector to return the index.

```
library(stringr)
library(rebus)

# Check the index
result <- str_which(sentenceList, or1(verbList))
result
# [1] 1 3 4
```